# Cypress 7.2.0 Upgrade, Import is Not a Module

Tags: typescript, node-modules, cypress, typescript-typings

I have just upgraded Cypress for my automation project from 6.2.1 to 7.2.0, now when I attempt to run the project with command `npm run cypress:open` with I get the error below. When I check my ***index.ts*** file in the plugin folder, my import from ***cypress-audit*** gives the error ***File 'C:/REPO/AutomationProject/node_modules/cypress-audit/index.d.ts' is not a module***. can anyone advise on how to fix this problem?

[image: Eror in browser]

[image: Error in plugins/index.ts]

Comment: It usualy means that the plugin needs to be reinstalled with something like `npm i <pluginName>`. Search your plugin library for the appropirate install command